# Topic modeling on the Devanagari (Hindi) text using Python

Tags: python, unicode, python-2.x

Can anyone help me how to deal with this decoding problem in Python?
I have got this output from the topic modeling of the hindi text in Python, Now I am not able to decode it in python to get the output in Devanagari (Hindi) language

```
[(0, u'0.573*"\u0915" + 0.360*"\u0930" + 0.304*"\u092e" + 0.270*"\u0928" + 0.246*"\u0938" + 0.217*"\u0932" + 0.189*"\u0926" + 0.189*"\u0924" + 0.184*"\u0939" + 0.182*"\u092f"'),
 (1, u'-0.485*"\u092e" + 0.381*"\u0924" + -0.359*"\u091f" + 0.307*"\u0935" + 0.260*"\u092c" + 0.229*"\u0926" + 0.202*"\u0939" + -0.147*"\u0938" + 0.133*"\u0926\u0930" + -0.126*"\u092a"'),
 (2, u'-0.378*"\u0938" + -0.343*"\u0932" + -0.295*"\u0935" + 0.276*"\u0930" + 0.272*"\u0915" + 0.268*"\u0926" + -0.253*"\u0939" + -0.192*"\u091f" + -0.163*"\u0926\u0930" + -0.148*"\u091c"'),
 (3, u'-0.508*"\u0930" + 0.392*"\u0924" + -0.323*"\u0938" + 0.296*"\u092e" + 0.179*"\u0939" + 0.178*"\u091a" + 0.169*"\u092f" + -0.166*"\u091c" + -0.133*"\u090f" + -0.125*"\u092a"'), 
 (4, u'0.514*"\u0938" + -0.308*"\u0917" + -0.280*"\u091c" + -0.256*"\u0930" + 0.229*"\u0939" + -0.227*"\u092f" + 0.208*"\u0915" + -0.201*"\u0928" + -0.175*"\u0932" + 0.173*"\u0926"')]
```

Comment: Those _are_ Devanagari codepoints. Are you using Python 2? FWIW, you're 1st string is `u'0.573*u"क" + 0.360*u"र" + 0.304*u"म" + 0.270*u"न" + 0.246*u"स" + 0.217*u"ल" + 0.189*u"द" + 0.189*u"त" + 0.184*u"ह" + 0.182*u"य"'`

Comment: Can you share me the python code, which will help me to convert it into like  u'0.573*u"क" + 0.360*u"र" + 0.304*u"म" + 0.270*u"न" + 0.246*u"स" + 0.217*u"ल" + 0.189*u"द" + 0.189*u"त" + 0.184*u"ह" + 0.182*u"य"'

Comment: You still didn't tell us what version of Python you are using. That's _very_ important for Unicode questions, since the Unicode handling of Python 2 is quite different to how it works in Python 3. FWIW, I used Python 3 to do that conversion. I'll post some Python 2 code shortly that you should find helpful.

Answer (score 3):

The strings such as `"\u0915"` that are embedded into your data *are* Unicode escape sequences of Devanagari glyphs. These escape sequences are used to maximise the portability of the data.

Here's some Python 2 code that uses a Regular Expression pattern to extract the numbers and glyphs from that data.

```
import re

data = [
    (0, u'0.573*"\u0915" + 0.360*"\u0930" + 0.304*"\u092e" + 0.270*"\u0928" + 0.246*"\u0938" + 0.217*"\u0932" + 0.189*"\u0926" + 0.189*"\u0924" + 0.184*"\u0939" + 0.182*"\u092f"'),
    (1, u'-0.485*"\u092e" + 0.381*"\u0924" + -0.359*"\u091f" + 0.307*"\u0935" + 0.260*"\u092c" + 0.229*"\u0926" + 0.202*"\u0939" + -0.147*"\u0938" + 0.133*"\u0926\u0930" + -0.126*"\u092a"'),
    (2, u'-0.378*"\u0938" + -0.343*"\u0932" + -0.295*"\u0935" + 0.276*"\u0930" + 0.272*"\u0915" + 0.268*"\u0926" + -0.253*"\u0939" + -0.192*"\u091f" + -0.163*"\u0926\u0930" + -0.148*"\u091c"'),
    (3, u'-0.508*"\u0930" + 0.392*"\u0924" + -0.323*"\u0938" + 0.296*"\u092e" + 0.179*"\u0939" + 0.178*"\u091a" + 0.169*"\u092f" + -0.166*"\u091c" + -0.133*"\u090f" + -0.125*"\u092a"'), 
    (4, u'0.514*"\u0938" + -0.308*"\u0917" + -0.280*"\u091c" + -0.256*"\u0930" + 0.229*"\u0939" + -0.227*"\u092f" + 0.208*"\u0915" + -0.201*"\u0928" + -0.175*"\u0932" + 0.173*"\u0926"')
]

pat = re.compile(r'(.*?)\*"(.*?)"\s*\+?\s*')

for i, row in data:
    print "\nRow", i
    t = [(float(w), s) for w, s in pat.findall(row)]
    for w, s in t: 
        print w, s
```

**output**

```
Row 0
0.573 क
0.36 र
0.304 म
0.27 न
0.246 स
0.217 ल
0.189 द
0.189 त
0.184 ह
0.182 य

Row 1
-0.485 म
0.381 त
-0.359 ट
0.307 व
0.26 ब
0.229 द
0.202 ह
-0.147 स
0.133 दर
-0.126 प

Row 2
-0.378 स
-0.343 ल
-0.295 व
0.276 र
0.272 क
0.268 द
-0.253 ह
-0.192 ट
-0.163 दर
-0.148 ज

Row 3
-0.508 र
0.392 त
-0.323 स
0.296 म
0.179 ह
0.178 च
0.169 य
-0.166 ज
-0.133 ए
-0.125 प

Row 4
0.514 स
-0.308 ग
-0.28 ज
-0.256 र
0.229 ह
-0.227 य
0.208 क
-0.201 न
-0.175 ल
0.173 द
```

To get this output, you should set your terminal to use UTF-8 encoding.

---

FWIW, here's your data in a more user-friendly form. To use it, you need to tell your editor to save your script with UTF-8 encoding, and you *must* have a valid UTF-8 encoding declaration at the start of the script, eg

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*- 

data = [
    (0, u'0.573*"क" + 0.360*"र" + 0.304*"म" + 0.270*"न" + 0.246*"स" + 0.217*"ल" + 0.189*"द" + 0.189*"त" + 0.184*"ह" + 0.182*"य"'),
    (1, u'-0.485*"म" + 0.381*"त" + -0.359*"ट" + 0.307*"व" + 0.260*"ब" + 0.229*"द" + 0.202*"ह" + -0.147*"स" + 0.133*"दर" + -0.126*"प"'),
    (2, u'-0.378*"स" + -0.343*"ल" + -0.295*"व" + 0.276*"र" + 0.272*"क" + 0.268*"द" + -0.253*"ह" + -0.192*"ट" + -0.163*"दर" + -0.148*"ज"'),
    (3, u'-0.508*"र" + 0.392*"त" + -0.323*"स" + 0.296*"म" + 0.179*"ह" + 0.178*"च" + 0.169*"य" + -0.166*"ज" + -0.133*"ए" + -0.125*"प"'),
    (4, u'0.514*"स" + -0.308*"ग" + -0.280*"ज" + -0.256*"र" + 0.229*"ह" + -0.227*"य" + 0.208*"क" + -0.201*"न" + -0.175*"ल" + 0.173*"द"')
]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I am using Python2, But these out put is not making any sense for the conclusion about topic So can you tell me how to do topic modeling on Devaragari (Hindi) text?. I have tried using LDA and got stuck with these output

Comment: @VishalKumarSingh: Sorry, I don't know anything about topic modeling or natural language processing. So I don't know what that data means, but I guess that those numbers are weights or probabilities of some kind. But that's a separate question to the Unicode problem. So maybe you should ask a fresh question, if you can figure out a way to state it that's on-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Can anyone tell me, how to do topic modeling on Devanagari (Hindi) text ??